# Image not displayed inline

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, inline

I am using bootstrap and I would like to display an image, followed by some text. However, no matter what I do, the text gets bumped to the next line, even though there is plenty of room after the image. Here is the code:

```
<div class="splash">
  <h1><img src="logo.png" style="width:120%;height:auto" class="gold"><small>text</small></h1>
</div>
```

I thought images were supposed to be inline by default, but just in case I added this class in my css sheet:

```
.gold {
    display: inline;
}
```

Can anyone explain why this is not working?

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is with the `width` that you manually set to `120%` with inline CSS. It's taking more than the full width (100%), there's no room remaining so the text is bumped to the next line.

If you remove that piece of code or change it to something smaller, it will work as expected.

Example : https://jsbin.com/quyogodawa/edit?html,output

Comment: Ok I checked the dev tools and you are partially correct; it is extending beyond the <h1> element. However there is plenty of room in the containing <div> element - the image is only about a quarter of the screen. Why won't the <h1> element extend further?

I have to do the 120% on the image to get it to be the right size.

Answer (score 1):

When I had these issues I would always go into the Dev Tools in the browser. You can then go to the CSS tab, select the area of your page and it will show you all the styles being applied to that section. 
You can tweak each style, add/remove on the fly, and see it change on your screen to figure out why it's not doing what you thought it should.

Each browser has it's own dev tools, and you access them by pressing F12.

Comment: To build on that, I suggest Chrome for viewing elements (AKA the page search div). Then for editing (styling) your website I suggest Mozilla Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your width and height values:

```
.gold {
    display: inline;
    width: auto;
    height: 100%;
}
```

I think the fact that you're setting `width` to be 120% is forcing the `small` text to take a new line

Answer (score 0):

Appears to be issues with my own .splash class, things work normally when I remove it. Not really sure why it would cause an issue though:

```
.splash {
    font-family: Ubuntu, sans-serif;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

Comment: Oops I had a width set on a .splash h1 block.